# Material tooltip with icon does not work on mobile phones

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I use angular 7 with material and I want to create an input field with the info icon in the end use matSuffix which is a tooltip. It works on the desktop, but it doesn't work on mobile phones.

I've created a stackblitz: https://angular-ncv2mp.stackblitz.io/
I've also tried to use with button, but it also doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we work on desktop- tooltip display just after do mouse hover on that particular element.

But On **Mobile - Tooltip works when doing a long press** on that particular element. Please try this.

If this will not work please update I will provide some other way.

Comment: It works with a simple text input, but it doesn't work with select input field. Could you provide me another solution?

Answer (score 26):

The MatTooltip correctly opens on mobile with a long press gesture by default.

But I suggest also to implement a toggle hide/show of the tooltip, on click of button, like this - because many mobile users do not understand that they need to longpress to see the tooltip:

```
<button type="button" matTooltip="I am a tooltip!" #tooltip="matTooltip" (click)="tooltip.toggle()" ...
```

This way, both solutions work on mobile: longpress and single tab toggle of tooltip.